# Docusign Connect issue -- Request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: docusignapi

I am supporting a web app that uses the DocuSign Connect API to handle signature processing.  We are running in production and demo environments (our production environment is using the DocuSign production environment; our demo envrionment is using the DocuSign demo environment).

The interface between my app and DocuSign Connect has been working smoothly for over a year.  Sometime in the last week or so, the demo environment began misbehaving.  In that time, the production environment has continued to work fine.

The problem is this:

In demo, when a signature event occurs, DocuSign is unable to call our callbackUrl.  The failure log indicates the following:

```
https://[mywebsite]/SignedDocument/DocuSignSignatureEvent :: Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

When I look at my DocuSign Connect Settings, I see a new setting -- "Require Mutual TLS" -- that does not exist in production. I'm not sure if this is related -- I have no idea when this setting was added to the demo environment.

Even though this is a demo app, it poses a problem for us (because our demos no longer completely work).  But it poses a much bigger problem if/when this same thing (via a code push or something else) begins happening in production.

Again, this interface has been working fine.  Nothing has changed on my web app since the last successful callback occurred (roughly a week ago).

Comment: Are you using a self-assigned cert? The `Require Mutual TLS` feature shouldn't impact your setup unless you have checked it. Which would require additional configuration on your end.

Comment: Please contact DocuSign Support, there's more information needed here to troubleshoot that you may not feel comfortable sharing on StackOverflow (such as the endpoint url)

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I am awaiting an answer from DocuSign.  I will post an update here if/when I know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this again, DocuSign Support indicates this should be resolved now.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue today.  Still have not heard from DocuSign.

Comment: DocuSign has indicated to me that this is a known problem on their end that they are working to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

We've been getting the same error starting today. Nothing has changed recently on our side to affect the demo environment. I'm thinking this might be an issue on DocuSign's end.

Comment: Please contact DocuSign Support, there's more information needed here to troubleshoot that you may not feel comfortable sharing on StackOverflow (such as the endpoint url)